# Will a .com domain name gain advantage over a .be domain name in SEO results for Americans

Tags: web, seo

My question to ask is whether a .com domain name will gain advantage over a .be domain name or any other when American people browse the internet, even if the website is totally written in English. In my country, Belgium, when I search the net, pages in Dutch pop up first, even if sometimes I search in English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO questions are off-topic. See meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes it will impact your SEO.

[Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=GY65Mlgw124) straight from Matt Cutts himself.